# Theano doesn't load on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, theano

I have an issue when importing Theano into a python script, I cloned the latest dev version as the 0.7.0 version didn't work either:

**error message:**

```
File "<ipython-input-1-1145adbc62d9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Michael/.spyder2-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Michael/.spyder2-py3')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Michael/.spyder2-py3/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import theano.tensor as T

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 22, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 12, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 638, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 126, in <module>
    preargs=args)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2196, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))

. collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit statusir_Windows-10-10.0.10586-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_60_Stepping_3_GenuineIntel-3.5.1-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:936: undefined reference to `__imp__Py_TrueStruct'Error' undefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' followow
```